# Can I safely bypass the door switch on my dryer?

Tags: repair, dryer

The door switch on my dryer is broken (the rocker part of the switch just hangs loose) and the dryer won't start.  I have the part number, but I won't be able to get one for several days.  Is this switch really just a switch?  Or does it serve some other function.  I'm wondering if it's relatively safe to just cut off the switch and short the wires together behind the molex connector for the next couple days until I can get the part.

Whirlpool dryer: part 3406104

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a safety switch designed to prevent the drum from turning while the door is open. If the switch were removed and the circuit closed by connecting the wires the drum will turn and the dryer will work. Can you get someone to tell you it is an okay thing to do, not likely.